# Data transformation of angles such that $90^\circ$ is equal to $-90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Is there a transformation I can perform on a dataset of angles (from $-90^\circ$ to $90^\circ$) such that the transformation of $-90^\circ$ is equal to that of $90^\circ$? I am only interested in what these angles represent geometrically, so $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ are both a vertical line. I just don't know how to convey this mathematically.

Furthermore, this transformation needs to reflect the actual geometrical interpretation of these angles. For example, $-80^\circ$ and $80^\circ$ are only $20^\circ$ apart (whereas in the number line they are $160^\circ$ apart).

Thanks.

Comment: not sure I understand the question

Comment: What do you mean by "transformation"?

Comment: I used the term transformation very loosely because I am not sure what kind of operations I could perform to my data to accomplish what I want.

Comment: I presume you're dealing with what's known as *axial data*, such as the angles made (to some given line) by undirected line segments, which would have the properties you suggest. Why do you need to transform them? I think it would help if you were more explicit (in your question) about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Double the angles, 180° will correspond to a full revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all angles are $\phi \in [-90°, +90°]$, the following transformation may do the trick: $$T(\phi) = sign(\phi) \cdot 90°-\phi$$

$$sign(x) := \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
\ \ \ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\ \ \ 1 & \text{if } x > 0 \end{cases}$$

**Examples**:

$T(+90°) = 90°-90°=0$

$T(-90°) = -90°-(-90°)=0$

$T(80°)-T(-80°) = 90°-80° - (-90°+80°) =  10°-(-10°)=20°$